# Javascript to show/hide div of render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3. I am trying to get a button to show or hide a div.

This is not returning any errors but nothing happens.

```
<input type=button value="Show Archived Postings" onclick="showHide('oldNews');">

<div id="oldNews">
<%= render 'archive_news' %>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(elementId) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element.style.visibility == 'visible') {
            element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (element.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
            element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It will always render my 'archive_news'. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Put alert or console.log and debug.

Comment: instead of visibility, try .display = "none"

Comment: @aw04 That's a test to see if the browser supports getElementById. EDIT: ...which isn't necessary unless you're supporting [earlier than IE 5.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById#Browser_Compatibility). You poor thing.

Comment: My server shows no log when I click the button. I did try .display = "none"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code for your requirement. You can use `style` property for hide and display element when you click on button.

```
//this would hide when body is loaded
var element = document.getElementById('oldNews');
if(element != null){
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

//this would hide when you click on input button
function showHide(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element != null) {
        if(element.style.display != 'none'){
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I make the div .display = 'none' when initially loaded?

Comment: you want to make div `display` none when page loaded?

Comment: Yes, I would the Archived News Postings to start invisible, then click to show and hide.